# Any XML binding frameworks for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

Is there any XML binding framework for Objective-C?

I've tried a few searches on google and didn't find anything yet.

I'm looking for something that reads from a XSD/DTD/XML and generate:

- the Model classes to store values
- the actual parser that reads from the XML and populate the model classes

Comment: Any luck finding something?  I've been curious about this myself.  So much so that I'm thinking about creating a framework if I can't find one.

Comment: How is it posible that Objective C doesn't support automated XML marshaling? I was appalled when I learned this...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vast and simple **tutorial** that helps to read as well as create xml documents using **GDataXMLParser** http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit of confusion about [SAXy](https://github.com/reaster/saxy). It is not another DOM library like NSXMLDocument or KissXML.

SAXy targets a different problem space, that of binding XML directly to domain objects using the lighter-weight [event driven model](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html).  It's more akin to JAXB or Castor in the Java world.

It's closest relative in the Objective-C realm is the modeling code in RestKit.  Although, RestKit advertises XML support, it's largely been dropped from the current version.  SAXy was written to fill the void.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `NSXMLDocument`.  Apple XML Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any external framework for XML-Binding, still I think you should check the Apple provided [solution](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/ModifyingXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001259-97363).

For parsing XML I preffer libxml2, [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) is a simple tutorial of how to embed this powerful parser in your project.

Hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

LibXML is the best solution for this requirement. It can load your DTD and parse the XML. You can also use XPath to map Model with the data inside XML structure

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether it works for you or not but **GData objective c library** from Google can solve your purpose . You can serach for GDataXML objective C on google. you will get the link to code.google.com . You can check out if they support this thing. GData is really a vast library , so may be it can solve the things for you .

Answer (score 0):

If the format is not important for you, you can use plist format ! This is a XML with DTD some different !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
```

However you can read directly this plist with NSDictionary (read NSDictionary documentation). It's so powerful and quick! No additional framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a full-featured XML Marshalling framework for Objective-C on github:

https://github.com/reaster/saxy

It has a clean API, automatically maps classes to elements, is highly configurable using the blocks and works on iOS with no third-party dependencies.