# Generate classes from XML Schema

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any XML binding frameworks for Objective-C ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262427/any-xml-binding-frameworks-for-objective-c)

Coming from a .NET background where you can easily generate an object model from an XML schema (through, for example xsd.exe) I wanted to know if there is a similar facility for generating Objective-C/NSObject objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: +1...I think its certainly a valid question, not sure why someone would downvote it.

Comment: Already looked at that post.. and that's fine when you have already hand-written the object model. In my case I'm trying to generate the model from an existing schema (XSD). Not at runtime though.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. But thinking in .NET and trying to find a synonym in Cocoa is a bad idea! Cocoa has NSProxy, forwarding methods, fallbacks for undefined keys etc. Please read also about KeyValueCoding. There is no need to generate code. Besides, Value Objects is a bad pattern in Cocoa.